# Problem with imagePicker in android, react native app with expo go

Tags: react-native, expo-go, expo-image-picker

recently my app has started showing a new problem.
while trying to access the camera, expo launches an unhandled exception:
Call to function 'ExponentImagePicker.launchCameraAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: User rejected permissions

meanwhile, i have granted permissions. in addition, the function ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync() always return a value of {"canAskAgain": false, "expires": "never", "granted": false, "status": "denied"}.

i could not find any way to re-grant the permission. up until a week ago, it all worked just fine.

any suggestion? anyone?

I tried to launch the camera, for no use. trying to run an old version of the app, where it all worked fine, resulted in the same error.
figured out it is a oriblem in my own device. re-installed expo app from play store, but it didnt load
when it finally did, it loaded old data which i could not get rid off